# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=13001, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

I keep getting this error in Firebase and can't seem to find an answer anywhere. (Admittedly I am about 2 weeks into learning android development). Thanks for any help!

[Screenshot of Firebase Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRZRI.png)

Here is the code for MainActivity.java

```
package com.dealmachine;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import io.branch.rnbranch.*;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        MainApplication.getCallbackManager().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "DealMachine";
    }

    // Override onStart, onNewIntent:
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        RNBranchModule.initSession(getIntent().getData(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
    }
}
```